# changing role of inner, outer regular of measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, outer-measure

In Billingsley's Book(Convergence of probability measure), There is a question about interchanging role of inner and outer regular. In book, they defined as

$$P(A) = \sup_{F \subset A}P(F) = \inf_{A \subset G}P(G)$$
that $G$ implies open set and $F$ implies closed set.

In book question, they ask in what condition this role interchanged, i.e.

$$P(A) = \sup_{G \subset A}P(G) = \inf_{A \subset F}P(F)$$

I tried to prove this as the existence of $P(A) = \sup_{F \subset A}P(F) = \inf_{A \subset G}P(G)$(they proved firstly at the closed set, and showed the satisfying set is $\sigma$-algebra. ), but it failed because countable intersection of closed set is not closed.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a largest open set contained in $A$, namely $A^{0}$ (the interior of $A$). So we get $P(A)=P(A^{0})$. Similarly the smallest closed set containing $A$  is it closure. So we get $P(A)=P(A^{0})=P(\overline A)$.  These are equivalent to the fact that $P(\partial A)=0$.

Comment: So it means that every measurable set has no boundary.

Comment: At least the boundary of any measurable set has probability $0$. @probafds123